# Transmission can't find downloaded movie in new location

Tags: transmission

I've downloaded a movie with Transmission. After the download, I've noticed it has downloaded into the wrong folder (Downloads instead of Videos), so I moved it to the desired folder.

Now, Transmission says "Error: No data found! Ensure your drives are connected or use 'Set Location'. To re-download, remove the torrent and re-add it."

I think "Set Location" is the way to go, but I may choose either the Videos folder or the movie folder inside Videos, nothing works: I still get the above error message. In the "Set Torrent Location" window, I have chosen "Local data is already there".

Am I doing something wrong, or Transmission really can't find the moved folder? I'm using version 2.84 (14307) in Debian Jessie.

EDIT

Someone told me to improve my questions, but really, what is wrong with it? I will never know, if the downvoter acts blindly like that...

Comment: Problems like this one are the reason I hardly ever mess with downloaded files. I do `cp -l` to my directory where I want it to be, leaving the source file in P2P `Video`, `Downloads` or wherever the program wants it to be.

Comment: I'd love to understand how the answer was useful, but not the question...

Comment: Maybe [some guy lost his keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/355310). You never know unless the voter leaves feedback. I didn't vote, neither the question, nor the answer. I'm here because the site engine suspected your comment replies to mine, so I was notified (if there were many commentators, I wouldn't have been). Users who voted won't probably ever see your comment. There's no way to tell who voted, nor to summon them. Someone like you [asked for feedback](https://meta.superuser.com/q/12627/432690), read the comments there. Just assume you got a stray downvote and carry on.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Stray downvotes should not be allowed, because they definitely suck!

Comment: You may find these interesting: [*Encouraging people to explain downvotes*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/355310), [*@Downvoter sends a notification to all downvoters for your post*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37090/355310).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes, mostly the second one. Thank you!

Comment: If you run "Verify Local Data" on the download, does it fix the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Your torrent client has no idea about where the new file is, or how much of it it has. I don't *specifically* have transmission but every single torrent client does this mostly the same way

Its a bit tricky here but.

1. Delete the torrent *leaving the data alone*. You don't want to accidentally delete the movie. I suggest a temporary location for less confusion. The point of this is to not redownload everything after all.
2. re add the movie pointing at the right directory and let it *just* start downloading. Pause it  This creates the files in a correct location so you can replace them. In most clients you can 'change download location'. We do want to start somewhere where we know the torrent client *will* look at the right place
3. Replace the new download with the old download
4. *Force recheck*   Cause your client just magically was given all the chunks by the torrent fairy.

Comment: A similar process is described [here on Transmission's forums.](https://forum.transmissionbt.com/viewtopic.php?t=9776)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Transmission and I just recently moved several files to my hard drive. Transmission cannot locate them anymore.

To fix this I right clicked the file that says "Error: No Data Found" and selected 'Move Data File to...' and found my new location (the new folder the files or folder are) and selected it.

I then had to wait a few seconds and click 'Resume Transfer' and it was all back to normal seeding properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).